# unix ssh find node.js file

Tags: node.js, file, unix, ssh

using ssh how come I can't find this file on my server?

find . -name lib/child_process.js

I know it's there because I'm using it and can see an error:

```
net.js:1054
if (port && handle.getsockname && port != handle.getsockname().port) {
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getsockname' of undefined
at net.js:1054:23
at Object.1:1 (cluster.js:587:5)
at handleResponse (cluster.js:171:41)
at respond (cluster.js:192:5)
at handleMessage (cluster.js:202:5)
at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
at child_process.js:387:7
at process.handleConversion.net.Native.got (child_process.js:91:7)
at process.<anonymous> (child_process.js:386:13)
```

child_process.js:387:7

I would like to find and edit (nano filename) this js file if anyone knows how to find / unhide it?

following this fix: https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node/commit/1dacde5a7d0c0363e811101d10140133c8245fbe

Comment: Why use `lib/foo` in your find command? That's extremely unlikely to find anything. Just give the filename.

Comment: no it keeps finding a file with the same name in my facebook-chat nodemodules (dependacies)

Comment: And nothing else? Could it be that that's a "built-in" file in node.js and not actually present in your filesystem as such ("compiled"-in or in a sort of archive)?

Comment: well the error code above says it's a process so you could well be right... how the hell have git users managed to edit code here: https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node/commit/1dacde5a7d0c0363e811101d10140133c8245fbe

Comment: Patches are usually apply to source trees, not installed applications. There might be "packaging" steps in producing node.js from its source. (I'm not familiar with it, this is just a guess.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, [issue 5330](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5330) and [issue 5774](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5774) might be of interest.

But, [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) is a [Core Module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules), and is actually compiled as part of the `node` executable.

> Node has several modules compiled into the binary. [...]
>
> The core modules are defined in node's source in the `lib/` folder.

If you want to apply an edit, you'll need a copy of the source code (either from [GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node) or a [distribution](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.15/)) to patch, compile, and install.

Node's [Installation Guide](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) may be worth checking out.